# How to make Maud (x-ray diffraction software) recognize java?

Tags: java, openjdk

I've had an error associated with java (which is already installed) while trying to run for first time Maud (X-ray diffraction software):

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(java.base/Paths.java:84)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleFinder.ofSystem(java.base/ModuleFinder.java:163)
    at jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(java.base/ModuleBootstrap.java:98)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase2(java.base/System.java:1917)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: default directory must be absolute
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.<init>(java.base/UnixFileSystem.java:54)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.<init>(java.base/LinuxFileSystem.java:39)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(java.base/LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:46)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(java.base/LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:39)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.<init>(java.base/UnixFileSystemProvider.java:56)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.<init>(java.base/LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(java.base/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.base/Constructor.java:453)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(java.base/Class.java:550)
    at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.createProvider(java.base/DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:48)
    at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(java.base/DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:63)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.<clinit>(java.base/FileSystems.java:91)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(java.base/Paths.java:84)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleFinder.ofSystem(java.base/ModuleFinder.java:163)
    at jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(java.base/ModuleBootstrap.java:98)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase2(java.base/System.java:1917)
```

I read how to fix the error by changing the java path in a initial file, but I can't figure this out in the Maud.sh file, which has:

```
#! /bin/sh -f
MAUD_PATH=`dirname "$0"`
cd $MAUD_PATH
java -mx1024M -Duser.dir=$MAUD_PATH -cp Maud.jar:lib/miscLib.jar:lib/JNIAltivec.jar:lib/EsquiClient.jar:lib/Help.jar:lib/Images.jar:lib/JGraph.jar:lib/JSgInfo.jar:lib/jgaec.jar:lib/Files.jar:lib/ij.jar:lib/HTTPclient.jar:lib/gl4java.jar it.unitn.ing.rista.Maud
```

I got a Ubuntu 16, x86. Maud file is on the home directory. Java version is openjdk 9-internal.

EDITED:
I tried `MAUD_PATH=$(realpath "$(dirname "$0")")` as @steeldriver said, and worked fine on one computer, but on another I got this other error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb72bae48, pid=6550, tid=6551
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode, serial gc, linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x18e48]  JNU_GetEnv+0x18
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/red/Maud/core.6550)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/red/Maud/hs_err_pid6550.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I *think* it's telling you that `user.dir` needs to be absolute: try `MAUD_PATH=$(realpath "$(dirname "$0")")`

Comment: @steeldriver , it worked exactly as you said, thank you so much!

Comment: ...however another error appeared as I tried to execute these instructions in a second machine.